# JVM crashes again and again with fatal error

Tags: fatal-error, jvm-crash

Facing issue in my production server. JVM crashed again and again. with the below fatal error. Point of crash is always be different.
JVM memory related information attached as Pic.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5cf7bc3de0, pid=29662, tid=0x00007f5cd4ef6700
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_231-b11) (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.231-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x987de0]  oopDesc* PSPromotionManager::copy_to_survivor_space<false>(oopDesc*)+0x730
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid29662.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Also when heck the sys.log there I got mysql communication failure exception.

Need Help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQPbo.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided it looks like you're simply running out of memory.

Comment: As from the below pic you can see. I have already given almost 18 GB max heap memory. Still its failing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQPbo.png

Comment: You need to provide more information but if you are sure it's that then I would examine how your application handles not being able to make the connection as if seems to not fail gracefully if that is the case